# Vertices lying under the object?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

I've only started learning blender, so I apologize if my question is obvious, but I failed to find the answer by googling.
I'm following the donut tutorial by blenderguru, and I've noticed that at some point my vertices "sunk" under the icing. They are not hidden, I tried to hide and reveal them (using H > Alt+H), they are under the icing.
At some point I tried to bring it up a little, so maybe I made a mistake there?
I would appreciate if someone could explain me how I can bring them back up again. Thank you in advance! I've attached a picture of how it currently looks like.

[image]

Comment: this isn't anything bad in general, I never did donut tutorial but you are probably using subdivision... subdivision increases vertices count and it makes your object "more smooth", but by making your object more smooth, some lines and vertices will change their position to give you that curve, as a result some vertices may end up like this underneath of another object... in some cases you would need to tweak it before subdivision is applied but for your example there is no need to worry as solidify modifier will hide it

Comment: thank you for replying!